# python get all ids startingwith a pattern

Tags: python

How to select all the elements starting with id123 in the following dictionary

```
b = {'id123_1': ['ddf', 1], 'id123_2': ['dff', 1], 'id789': ['ddf', 1]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> b = {'id123_1': ['ddf', 1], 'id123_2': ['dff', 1], 'id789': ['ddf', 1]}
>>> [v for k,v in b.iteritems() if k.startswith('id123')]
[['dff', 1], ['ddf', 1]]
```

or

```
>>> [k for k,v in b.iteritems() if k.startswith('id123')]
['id123_2', 'id123_1']
```

or some other variant of this, it isn't very clear which output is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over keys of the dict ans see if key [`startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) given id:

```
elements = [values for key,values in b.iteritems() if key.startswith('id123')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If by elements you mean `key-value` pairs, this is the way to go:

```
elements = [(k, v) for k, v in b.iteritems() if k.startswith('id123')]
```